# OS X Mouse Location Issues

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I am trying to slow down the mouse cursor programmatically by multiplying the mouse delta by a number between 1 and 0 on every mouse move event. It's working fine for the X axis, but the Y position always gets moved back to the center of the screen, it's very bizarre.

I can't seem to figure out why the Y position of the cursor gets moved towards the center of the screen no matter whether you move the mouse up up or down...

I set up a CGEventTap for mouse move events, and this is the code for the callback:

```
CGEventRef 
mouse_filter(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, float *speed_modifier) {


    CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(event);
    NSPoint old_point = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
    CGPoint target; 

    int tX = point.x; 
    int tY = point.y; 
    float oX = old_point.x;
    float oY = old_point.y;
    float dX = tX-oX;
    float dY = tY-oY;


    dX*=0.1, dY*=0.1;
    tX = round(oX + dX);
    tY = round(oY + dY);


    target = CGPointMake(tX, tY);

    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(target);




    return false;
}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

I logged some values during the running of the application and discovered that `oY` does not seem to contain the expected values... it seems to always be close to 430, usually within a couple pixels of that. `tY` contains the seemingly correct target value, so it stands to reason that `oY` from one iteration should be equal to `tY` from the previous one (it works properly for the X values), however, `oY` is always close to 430, even when the mouse should be moving towards the top of the screen.  This makes me think that `dY` is somehow being set to a value that will bring `oY` back to around 430, but I can't figure out how that is happening, as `dY` seems to output the correct value as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(event);`
is a point where  (0,0) is the **top** left of the screen.

`NSPoint old_point = [NSEvent mouseLocation];`
is a point where (0,1) is the **bottom** left of the screen.

I if I get the screen height, and do:

'oY = abs(oY - screen_height+1);`, oY is now based off the top Left of the screen, and my application works properly.